# merging two pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Hello Im having troubles merging two Pandas dataframes, tryed merge and concat but I just cannot get the format I want, Im using 2 row indexes and all columns names are the same :

```
    df1                                     df2

           high   low                              high low
 year ind                                 year ind
 2000  A    9      5                      2000  B    8    3      
 2001  A    5      2                      2001  B    4    2
```

I want something like :

```
   df3                                  

           high   low                         
 year ind                                
 2000  A     9     5    
 2000  B     8     3                      
 2001  A     5     2            
 2001  B     4     2
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
print (df)
          high  low
year ind           
2000 A       9    5
     B       8    3
2001 A       5    2
     B       4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Append here

```
df1.append(df2)
Out[149]: 
          high   low
year ind            
2000 A       9     5
2001 A       5     2
2000 B       9     5
2001 B       5  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

From pandas.merge docstring,

> Docstring: Merge DataFrame objects by performing a database-style join
>   operation by columns or indexes.

it likely aims at merging two dataframes 
horizontally. If you just want to have fun, you can do the trick as following. However, this might be a silly solution but if did the work.

```
pd.merge(df1.T, df2.T, left_index=True, right_index=True).T
```